# arrow ensure doesn't make value non nullable after check

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

have a question about `ensure` function, somehow it doesn't make null safe after check in either block.
What I am doing wrong, or is there a better way to ensure that value is not null except of using `!!`
here is my code

```
 suspend fun checkCanConnectDirectChat(
    senderId: Int?,
    receiverId: Int?,
    chatRoomId: Int?
  ) = either {
    ensure(chatRoomId != null && receiverId != null) {
      BadRequestExceptionResponse(message = ErrorConstants.INVALID_PAYLOAD)
    }

    val isSenderInChat = isUserInChat(chatRoomId, senderId).bind()
    val isReceiverInChat = isUserInChat(chatRoomId, receiverId).bind()
    ensure(isSenderInChat && isReceiverInChat){
      BadRequestExceptionResponse(message = ErrorConstants.INVALID_PAYLOAD)
    }
  }
```

after the ensure I still see that they are nullable
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the compiler is not "clever enough" to know that if the check inside `ensure` talks about null-ness, then within the block that holds. The best solution is to use the `*NotNull` family of functions, some of them available at Arrow, some of them available in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would use `ensureNotNull`, which smart-casts the value to be not nullable.

```
suspend fun checkCanConnectDirectChat(
    senderId: Int?,
    receiverId: Int?,
    chatRoomId: Int?
  ) = either {
    ensureNotNull(chatRoomId) {
     BadRequestExceptionResponse(message = ErrorConstants.INVALID_PAYLOAD)
    }

    ensureNotNull(receiverId) {
     BadRequestExceptionResponse(message = ErrorConstants.INVALID_PAYLOAD)
    }
    val isSenderInChat = isUserInChat(chatRoomId, senderId).bind()
    val isReceiverInChat = isUserInChat(chatRoomId, receiverId).bind()
    ensure(isSenderInChat && isReceiverInChat){
      BadRequestExceptionResponse(message = ErrorConstants.INVALID_PAYLOAD)
    }
  }
```

Comment: yeah, but this is 2 checks instead of one(

Comment: An alternative is to use this:


```kotlin
either { 
  if(chatRoomId != null && receiverId != null) { 
   shift(BadRequestExceptionResponse(message = ErrorConstants.INVALID_PAYLOAD))
  }
   ....
}
```


If only one check is wanted